# Twisted Error: Request.write called on a request after Request.finish was called

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I'm trying to put slow computations inside threads, and getting an error "Request.write called on a request after Request.finish was called."

I've looked through answers already, and find exact the same question, but the solution not working for me. Please advise.

```
from twisted.web.server import Site, NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, threads
from twisted.python import log

import sys
import time


def SlowComputation():
    time.sleep(10)
    return "Lang Computation Result"


def FastComputation():
    return "Fast Computation Result"


class PerformComputation(Resource):
    def Success(self, request):
        request.write('Success')
        request.finish()

    def Failure(self, request):
        request.write('Failure')
        request.finish()

    def render_GET(self, request):
        if 'fast' in request.args:
            d = threads.deferToThread(FastComputation)
            d.addCallback(self.Success(request))
            return NOT_DONE_YET
        if 'slow' in request.args:
            d = threads.deferToThread(SlowComputation)
            d.addCallback(self.Success(request))
            return NOT_DONE_YET


log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
root = Resource()
root.putChild("calculate", PerformComputation())
factory = Site(root)
reactor.listenTCP(8880, factory, interface='localhost')
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
d.addCallback(self.Success(request))
```

is the same as:

```
temp = self.Success(request)
d.addCallback(temp)
```

which, given the definition of `Success` is the same as:

```
request.write('Success')
request.finish()
temp = None
d.addCallback(None)
```

This probably fails with *Request.write called on a request after Request.finish was called.* because `d.addCallback(None)` raises an exception and the server tries to report the error as the response.  However, since `finish` has already been called it can't write the error.

The correct way to add a callback to a `Deferred` with an extra argument is `d.addCallback(self.Success, request)`.  Callbacks on a `Deferred` **always** get passed the result of the `Deferred` as the first argument, though - so the correct signature for `Success` is:

```
def Success(self, result, request):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Jean-Paul, your input is very valuable. Also, I've figured my typo in the code.